# English to Predicate Logic (Imply and AND)

Tags: logic

The question is:

> If Bob is happy, then all his friends are happy

My attempt looks like:

$happy(bob) \Rightarrow (\forall x(friend(x, bob) \wedge happy(x)))$

The answer is

$happy(bob) \Rightarrow (\forall x(friend(x, bob) \color{red}{\Rightarrow} happy(x)))$

So is my answer acceptable too? If not why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer translates into pseudo-logic as

> If Bob is happy, then { for all $x$: $x$ is friends with Bob and $x$ is happy }

whereas what you want is

> If Bob is happy, then { for all $x$: if $x$ is Bob's friend then $x$ is happy }

Comment: Oh so I might be missing out if some friends of bob are unhappy?

Comment: No - your answer says that *everyone* is friends with Bob. You need to say that people are happy *if* they are friends with Bob (which is why you need the implication). If someone is not friends with Bob, then we don't know if they're happy or unhappy.